# Weird boundaries with a color of white

Tags: iphone, xcode, react-native

I get these weird 'whitish' boundaries. No idea why does this happen.
Tried to resolve it by changing the values for backgroundColor(made use of 'transparent' as well), but they don't go away.
My intention is to get a button with a single solid background color.

Why does this 'whitish' thing appear? How do I remove them?

This 'whitish' thing appears on iPhone 6 plus and iPhone 6s plus.
It does not appear on iPhone 6, 6s, 5, 5s(not tested on any other).
I have not tested this on an actual device, rather done so on a simulator(the usual Xcode simulator).

The 'whitish' thing does not appear on my android phone(haven't tested on an android emulator). 
The phone I used was a Moto G 1st Gen(5.1 Android).

```
class something extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{left: 12}}>
        <View style={[styles.byView]}>
         <Text style={[styles.byText]}>Weird</Text>
        </View>
       </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   )
  }
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: 'red'
 },
 byView: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  width: 112,
  height: 33,
  borderColor: 'blue',
  borderWidth: 1.5,
  backgroundColor: 'green'
 },
 byText: {
  color: 'white',
  fontSize: 12
 },
});
```

[image: Simulator-screenshot]

Comment: try removing `space-between` from `buttonLine`

Comment: Removed that <View> but it doesn't go away.